# Emacs Mode for Reddit, (void-variable hierarchy--make)

Tags: variables

Trying to add md4rd, using this:

```
(use-package md4rd :ensure t
  :config
  (add-hook 'md4rd-mode-hook 'md4rd-indent-all-the-lines)
  (setq md4rd-subs-active '(emacs lisp+Common_Lisp prolog clojure))

  (run-with-timer 0 3540 'md4rd-refresh-login))
```

, but I get this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable hierarchy--make)
  byte-code("\302\303!\210\302\304!\210\302\305!\210\306\307\310\10!\311\11!\"\312\313!\314\315\316\317\"!\320\315\316\317\"!\321\315\316\317\"!%\207" [hierarchy--make hierarchy-- require seq map subr-x cl-defstruct hierarchy :constructor :conc-name roots nil parents make-hash-table :test equal children seen-items] 9)
  require(hierarchy)
  byte-code("\300\301!\210\300\302!\210\300\303!\210\300\304!\210\300\305!\210\300\306!\210\300\307!\210\300\310!\207" [require hierarchy cl-lib cl-extra dash request json s tree-mode] 2)
  require(md4rd nil t)
  (not (require 'md4rd nil t))
  (if (not (require 'md4rd nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'md4rd) :error) (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Configuring package md4rd") (prog1 (condition-case err (progn (add-hook 'md4rd-mode-hook 'md4rd-indent-all-the-lines) (setq md4rd-subs-active '(emacs lisp+Common_Lisp prolog clojure)) (run-with-timer 0 3540 'md4rd-refresh-login) t) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning132 :config err))) (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract ... now)))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Configuring package md4rd" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Configuring package md4rd"))))))
  (prog1 (if (not (require 'md4rd nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'md4rd) :error) (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Configuring package md4rd") (prog1 (condition-case err (progn (add-hook 'md4rd-mode-hook 'md4rd-indent-all-the-lines) (setq md4rd-subs-active '...) (run-with-timer 0 3540 'md4rd-refresh-login) t) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning132 :config err))) (let ((elapsed (float-time ...))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Configuring package md4rd" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Configuring package md4rd")))))) (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) now)))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package md4rd" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package md4rd"))))
  (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package md4rd") (prog1 (if (not (require 'md4rd nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'md4rd) :error) (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Configuring package md4rd") (prog1 (condition-case err (progn (add-hook ... ...) (setq md4rd-subs-active ...) (run-with-timer 0 3540 ...) t) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning132 :config err))) (let ((elapsed ...)) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Configuring package md4rd" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Configuring package md4rd")))))) (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) now)))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package md4rd" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package md4rd")))))
  (condition-case err (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package md4rd") (prog1 (if (not (require 'md4rd nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'md4rd) :error) (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Configuring package md4rd") (prog1 (condition-case err (progn ... ... ... t) (... ...)) (let (...) (if ... ... ...))))) (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract ... now)))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package md4rd" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package md4rd"))))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning132 :catch err)))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 232936
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/b0ef/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0xde439016bde6cc4>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c61addc0b4d35>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Search for `void-variable` to find duplicate questions. When you find one, please delete this one. Thx.